# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, task, smartphone

this is my app\build.gradle file..........................

```dart
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 31
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.ccounterr"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
            minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion 31
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
```

```
**this is my android\build.gradle file.............................**
```

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
    
    rootProject.allprojects {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core') {
                        details.useVersion "1.0.2"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.lifecycle') {
                        details.useVersion "2.0.0"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.versionedparcelable') {
                        details.useVersion "1.0.0"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.fragment') {
                        details.useVersion "1.0.0"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.appcompat') {
                        details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.annotation') {
                        details.useVersion "1.0.2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is error when running on android device.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1831 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[Fatal Error] tracing-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] window-java-1.0.0-beta04.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] loader-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] customview-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] viewpager-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e
      > Could not resolve androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/tracing/tracing/1.0.0/tracing-1.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e
      > Could not resolve androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/window/window-java/1.0.0-beta04/window-java-1.0.0-beta04.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/loader/loader/1.0.0/loader-1.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/customview/customview/1.0.0/customview-1.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/viewpager/viewpager/1.0.0/viewpager-1.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

```
>I have tried these things
```

1. I tried upgrading the gradle url in gradle wrapper.properties file.
2. I tried changing my compilesdk version 31.
3. I tried chnaging my tragetsdk version to 31.............................

> It is ruuning properly on web

Comment: There's an issue with your gradle files if you have this `com.google.gms.google-services` in your gradle it would be safe to try it with version `4.3.15`

Comment: i add that classpath in my project level build.gradle file on your advice, but it didn't work @Ghazanfar Ateeb

Comment: please anyone answer my queston...please